# Spring Data REST custom API url for HATEOAS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

What I've known are:

1. If I define a custom method in the Repository interface, it will show in the URL like `http://localhost/{repository}/search/{myMethod}`. For example, I can define a `recent` method in the `Order` Repository interface (I can do this by using @Query simple and clean) and I can get the most recent object via `http://localhost/order/search/recent`.
2. If I use `@RepositoryRestController` to make a custom controller class, I have to implement HATEOAS using `Resource` and `Resources` myself and add a link. But I will get the right URL I want like `http://localhost/{myPath}`. For example, if I want to get the most recent objects of `Order`, I have to write codes below:

   ```
   @RepositoryRestController
   public class RecentOrdersController {

       private OrderRepository orderRepo;

       @Autowired
       public RecentOrdersController(OrderRepository orderRepo) {
           this.orderRepo = orderRepo;
       }

       @GetMapping(path = "/orders/recent", produces = "application/hal+json")
       public ResponseEntity<Resources<OrderResource>> recentOrders() {
           PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(
                   0, 12, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
           List<Order> orders = orderRepo.findAll(page).getContent();
           List<OrderResource> orderResources =
                   new OrderResourceAssembler().toResources(orders);
           Resources<OrderResource> recentResources =
                   new Resources<OrderResource>(tacoResources);
           recentResources.add(
                   linkTo(methodOn(RecentOrdersController.class).recentOrders())
                       .withRel("recents"));
           return new ResponseEntity<>(recentResources, HttpStatus.OK);
       }
   }
   ```

   and then:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ResourceProcessor<PagedResources<Resource<Order>>>
       orderProcessor(EntityLinks links) {
           return new ResourceProcessor<PagedResources<Resource<Order>>>() {
           @Override
           public PagedResources<Resource<Order>> process(
               PagedResources<Resource<Order>> resource) {
               resource.add(
               links.linkFor(Order.class)
                   .slash("recent")
                   .withRel("recents"));
               return resource;
           }
       };
   }
   ```

I have to write the `OrderResource` and `OrderResourceAssembler` myself and which make this even worse is that there may many other domains like `Person` in the `Order` domain, I have to wirte the `xxxResource` and `xxxResourceAssembler` myself too.

My question is how can I combine those?

For example, if I define a domain class named `Order` and enable the spring data REST, how can I get the most recent orders via URL like `http://localhost/recent` with fully HATEOAS support at minimal effort?

Comment: What does it matter what the URL is? You can give the rel a meaningful name so I don't see that anyone would care what the URL is.

Comment: @Alan Hay 1. I think the /recent make more sense for developer who want to use this API. The /search prefix may mislead to provide parameters. 2. I am wondering how to reuse the Data REST.

Comment: The whole point of the thing is that client apps obtain URLs by looking a the rel names, not by hardcoding URLs. I am not sure what your second point means.

Comment: @AlanHay The second point is, whether there're some beans like `Resources<Resource<Order>>` I can reuse via `@Autowired` or something like this.